# Sponsored links for this tag section no longer on the sidebar?

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Is this a new change, or a bug? This is just on /questions so I don't know what "this tag" refers to, also I have high enough rep I thought I'd be ad free.

[image: Sponsored links for this tag]

Comment: Chiming in here as well. I've never seen this on a main page before. Also seems to be hard-coded to the HTML5 tag -- I see the exact same list.

Comment: [I posted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305606/randomly-getting-a-sponsored-tag-on-the-homepage) 1 minute after you. :P

Comment: I seriously don't like it! Please let me opt out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing to see here move along...Well, nothing now.

There was a bit of a blip that targeted the sponsored tags to all tags. It is now resolved.

Comment: Just having some fun over here in Ad Ops. Move along, nothing to see here... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NNOrp_83RU