# Randomly getting a sponsored tag on the homepage

Tags: bug, homepage, sponsored-tags

[image: Sponsored tag on the homepage]

This is the view i get right now on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive. I reloaded and got the same thing.

I don't know why it suddenly think that the homepage is owned by IgniteUI.