# What does data analysis have to do with Angular?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags

I refreshed one of the tags I monitored today to find this monstrosity from looker at the top of the page:

[image: Five sponsored links from Looker, each related to data analysis and preparation.]

Beyond that taking up a totally unreasonable amount of screen real estate (which others have mentioned) what on earth does that tech have to do with Angular (a general-purpose SPA framework)?

Usually the idea is that ads are relevant to us... and I just don't see it here.

Comment: The same ad is shown on all tags. Even if you check tags that are just created.

Comment: Well that's doubly messed up then

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305604/1896169

Comment: And, all links go to the same place.

Comment: It was confirmed as a bug by animuson here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371779/would-it-be-possible-to-not-allow-tag-sponsorship-for-those-tags-which-are-being#comment615605_371779

Comment: Is there a reason we aren't saying the name "looker" in the body of the post? It's basically impossible to find this meta post that affects most of the site.

Comment: @Shepmaster Just didn't think it was super relevant. Added to make it easier to search :)

Comment: Cool. Wasn't sure if we were trying to avoid more free advertising for them ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure we could do much better in that department than having that ad on the top, in a giant block, of **every tag search**. One mention here won't do anything :) @Shepmaster

Comment: @BhargavRao That post is deleted, if you weren't aware. I have a vague feeling I remember seeing it (the title sounds familiar).

Comment: @Draco18s, The question was posted by me and I deleted it as it was a needless duplicate. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Ah, gotcha.

Comment: This is definitely not intended. Looking into it now.

Comment: Who knew a salesman could hack the system?!?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've paused that particular ad. It's not clear how this happened yet. Setting up those tag-sponsorship ads is surprisingly complicated, and it could have been human error, or it might be a bug in the tool we built to assist in setting them up. Our ad-ops team will start looking into it tomorrow. Either way, hopefully you'll never see a site-wide tag-takeover like this again.

We really appreciate you pointing it out.

Comment: Just to get my thoughts clarified ... [would some person check the tag wiki before sponsoring, or is it automated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371779/would-it-be-possible-to-not-allow-tag-sponsorship-for-those-tags-which-are-being)

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm not on the ad ops team, but I'm pretty sure they try to do as much manual-checking as possible when new ads go live or edits are made. There's a decent chance that the issue was triggered by an automated process which tries to synchronize certain data with Google's API. We've occasionally seen unexplainable behavior triggered by the API before.

Comment: Well, it did happen again.