# What's with the Looker icon?

Tags: discussion, bug-reporting-process

Just started to see this graphic on many question list pages I have on my watch list.

[image]

Is this a new 'feature' or a bug? Refresh loads the image again in the same place.

Chrome under Win10 on a Surface Pro.

Comment: It is part of the "Sponsored links for this tag" block, [which as of now is being displayed on all tags due to a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371776/2751851).

Comment: This isn't a duplicate; these are two separate bugs. One is the fact that the looker sponsored links are appearing on all the tags, and the other is the looker icon appearing on top of the featured questions element. I don't know if these issues will be solved by the same fix since I don't know what the fix is, but whoever is programming this fix needs to know that this issue exists in addition to the "looker being displayed on all tags" bug.

Comment: Also @Jeeped, please use the [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug) tag. The [bug-reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug-reports/info) tag is for questions about bug reports, wheras the [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug) tag is for the actual reporting of bugs.