# Sponsored tag bug again

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags

Hazelcast sponsored links are appearing on tags they shouldn't. [Last time, it was Looker.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371776/what-does-data-analysis-have-to-do-with-angular) Looks like we've got a regression.

[image: bad sponsored links]

Comment: I was just about to post the same. I'm seeing the hazelcast links on every tag.

Comment: @RobertColumbia What makes you think that the spam tag is appropriate? The official response to the previous occurrence was _"...it could have been human error, or it might be a bug in the tool we built..."_.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is Jinming on the ad ops team at Stack Overflow.

First off, we are really sorry for the confusion and thank you for bringing this to our attention. We have fixed this error yesterday and our dev team has been working on a permanent fix on the tool that had caused it.

Thank you for bearing with us and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: ... is this... is this legit?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes.

Comment: There should be a ♦ symbol alternative for employee-but-not-moderator.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Just to teach how to fish ... the employee data is available on the API. You can [use this API call to make sure that Jinming Zhang is a legit employee](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/8564218?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!-.x35QtPDaMa). You can use this API call to determine if a user is an employee or not `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/USER_ID_HERE?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=!-.x35QtPDaMa`.

Comment: @jpmc26, it's through the user ID. This is the API call without any filters https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/8564218?site=stackoverflow. But true, I agree that employees must be differentiated from other users in someway.

Comment: This's the latest discussion on that: [Split visualization of employee and moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341657/4099593)

Comment: What is the quota shown in that API?

Comment: @PaulKaram, the number of API calls you can make in 1 day

Comment: FYI I'm pretty sure employees can opt to have the diamond next to their name, but they don't need to. A little bizarre when their bio leads nowhere either but I don't make the rules

Comment: @Tas where did you get that info from? I'd like to know if it's true.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I may have misinterpreted something, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161197/keep-employee-on-the-profile-of-se-employees-on-meta) suggests that employees may also have the diamond when they need it (depending on their role), but some employees won't have it. So it may not be as much as them _choosing_ to have it or not, vs them needing it, I guess I simply meant that some employees have a diamond, and other employees don't. And there seems to be discussions about this, mostly on meta.stackexchange (you can find them from the linked post)